# Android ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor cause: null

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm tearing my hair out with this one! I'm a newbie to Android so I'm sure it's something super obvious.

I'm getting a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` exception where `cause: null`

All I want is a seperate thread that runs whenever the activity is on screen!

```
// Instance Variables
private ScheduledExecutorService m_oScheduledExecutor = null;

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
super.onResume();

if (oScheduledExecutor == null)
{
    oScheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
}

    try
    {
        oScheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate({Runnable Instance HERE}, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("(MainActivity) Error: " + e.getMessage() + " Cause: " + e.getCause());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    m_oScheduledExecutor.shutdown();
}
```

EDIT: Entire Stack Trace....

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@41976688 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@4195c7f8[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1979)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:786)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:545)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(Executors.java:619)
at com.example.wifitest.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:61)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot 'recycle' an `ExecutorService`.  Once you have invoked `shutdown()`, attempting to schedule any task will cause a rejection, and in your case the rejection policy is to throw `RejectedExecutionException`.

If you follow your stacktrace, you can see in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
/**
 * Specialized variant of ThreadPoolExecutor.execute for delayed tasks.
 */
private void delayedExecute(Runnable command) {
    if (isShutdown()) {
        reject(command);
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Keeping your executor service as an instance variable is not going to work for you here: once it's been shutdown, it can't be used again.

Answer (score -1):

Do not shutdown the ScheduledExecutorService inside onStop() method. Try to put it inside onDestroy() method. When your activity goes in background, onStop() method might be getting called, as your activity is not visible in the background. Because of this, if the ScheduledExecutorService is shutdown, you might be getting this error.