# Stopping and starting Scheduled Executor properly

Tags: java, android, executorservice

I am currently stopping and starting a `Scheduled Executor` as follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    ...
    ...
}


protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodicTask, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("ACTIVITY HAS BEEN RESUMED");
}


protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    System.out.println("ACTIVITY HAS BEEN STOPPED");
    executor.shutdownNow();
    executor = null;
}
```

I was wondering whether this is actually the correct way to stop and start an `Executor Service`.

Can this implementation potentially cause any problems down the line?

I also referred to this question in trying to come up with a solution for this:
[Android ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor cause: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143427/android-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-cause-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will add some critiques, but this approach is fairly solid.

First comment, there is the potential where `onStop()` is not called. Such a case is described at the very bottom of [Starting an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html). As such, I would consider moving the Executor creation and destruction to different corresponding methods. If you'd like to keep the creation in `onResume()`, then place the destruction and cleanup in `onPause()`. Likewise, if you'd like to move the creation to `onCreate(...)` then move the destruction and cleanup to `onDestroy()`. I personally prefer the latter for two reasons: if it's tied to the Activity and I expect it to run in the background then I will put it in `onCreate(...)` so that the process can continue operating even if the Activity is no longer in focus. Additionally, `onDestroy()` is guaranteed to be called, even if the app is forceable closed by the OS.

As for the actual code cleanup, I assume that `periodicTask` is a `ScheduledFuture`, but we all know about assumptions. Anyways, a `ScheduledFuture` has a method for canceling the running task in addition to being able to shutdown the `Service`. So you can implement a finish method along the lines of:

```
private void finishScheduledExecutor() {
    if (periodicTask != null) {
        periodicTask.cancel(false); // true if it can be interrupted, false if you'd like it 
                              // to finish its current iteration
    }
    if (executor != null) {
        executor.shutdown(); // shutdown will allow the final iteration to finish 
                             // executing where shutdownNow() will kill it immediately
    }
}
```

I like to explicitly close and release resources, especially with threading involved, whenever possible. However, it is not absolutely necessary. `shutdownNow()` is adequate for terminating the `ExecutorService` and `periodicTask`.

Comment: Followed the second approach :oncreate() and onDestroy() as I need it in activity